# Threaded/Nested/Hierachial Comments

Tags: php, sql

I'm having troubles working something out. I have just used a threaded comment example online, tested it against manually inputted data and works perfectly.

[image]

But this setup is kind of strange. It uses a PATH method, so the first comment has a path of 01, a reply to that comment has a path of 01_01 and another reply to the first comment would have 01_02. You can see the relative paths in my screenshot (above), next to each name.

This method performs really well, as I have tested it against many, many comments. The problem I have is calculating the next reply path. For example, let's say my user clicks [reply] on Jeremy Clarkson's comment, which has a path of 01_01_01. The next sequence to this would be 01_01_02, but that has already been used by Kim Bauer's comment. I thought I could do a little query `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE path LIKE '01_01_%'` and select the last row and add 1 to it, but the comment from Chloe O'Brien has 01_01_01_01, which would affect this result.

Can somebody please explain how I can calculate the next correct path for a reply?

**My Fix:**

I calculate the next available path by doing this:

```
SELECT path
FROM blog_comments
WHERE path LIKE '01_01___'
ORDER BY path DESC
LIMIT 1

$last_path = $row[0];
$last_path_suffix = substr($last_path,strrpos($last_path,'_')+1);
$next_path_suffix = str_pad($last_path_suffix+1,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
$next_path = substr($last_path,0,strlen($last_path)-strlen($last_path_suffix)).$next_path_suffix;
```

**If anybody would like to use this method, the printing goes something like this:**

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY path ASC;";

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $nesting_depth = strlen($row['path']) - strlen(str_replace('_','',$row['path']));
    $left_margin = $nesting_depth * 40; // 40 pixels nesting indent

    echo '<div class="comment_item" style="margin-left:'.$left_margin.'px;">';
        echo '<strong>'.htmlspecialchars($row['author_name']).'<br>';
        echo htmlspecialchars($row['comment']).'<br>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I think it might be better to drop the path idea and go for a simple `id`, `parentid` solution.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I'm giving this solution two more hours of my patience, then I might switch to `id>parent_id` method :)

Comment: Next to parentID, you might want to learn a little about so called nested sets. Each of the methods has pros and cons, so it's normally good to know the different approaches for more alternatives.

Comment: @ShadowStorm do you have a sample source code of this method somewhere in github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for exactly two digits using two underscores `__`. Underscore is a wildcard that matches exactly one unknown character. And you should escape the literal underscores since `_` is a wildcard character.

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE path LIKE '01\_01\___' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: I'm glad you added that last update explaining what two underscores meant. I was just writing to ask :) I will have a crack at this and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Got this to work with some slight adjustments. Firstly, ESCAPE isn't a MySQL function (my fault for not specifying this). I also had trouble escaping the non-wildcard underscores, so instead, I used LIKE `'01_01___'` which now appears to work fine.